# Snap.svg - How to transform various elements to absolute center?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

The plunker below shows my rough animations with an SVG map of the USA.

https://plnkr.co/edit/gXWTk1fGeVUOQJM52OPs?p=preview

```
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 959 593"></svg>
```

JS:

```
var states = s.selectAll('.state');

states.forEach(function(element) {
    element.click(function(){
        this.attr({
            fill: 'red'
        });

        if (!this.isTransformed) {
            svg.animate({
                transform: 's10'
            });
            this.animate({
            // the transform
            transform: 'R 360 S 3 T0, 0',
         }, 750, mina.easeout);
            this.transform('T0,0');
            this.isTransformed = true;
            activeRegion = this.node.id;

            states.forEach(function(element) {
                if (element.node.id !== activeRegion) {
                    element.addClass('ng-hide');
                }
            });
        } else {
            states.forEach(function(element) {
                element.removeClass('ng-hide');
            });

            this.animate({
            transform: 'R 0 S 1',
            fill: '#E0E0E0'
         }, 750, mina.easeout);
            this.isTransformed = false;
        }
    });

    element.mouseover(function(){
        this.attr({fill: "yellow"});
    });

    element.mouseout(function(){
        this.attr({fill: "#E0E0E0"});
    });
});
```

This plunker uses [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) to load an existing [SVG](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_US_Map.svg).

When you click on individual states, a rough animation occurs.  States on the outer edges of the map are not completely visible.

**I'm wondering how to `transform` all states to the center of the paper?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the bounding box of the outer element, in the example I have put the states groups all in an outer group and taken the bounding box of that (you could just append it to a group you have added if needed). That element is called '#outer'. You could try just getting the bbox of the outer svg, but I'm not sure how reliable that is with different browers.

Get the bounding box on it, eg.

```
var outerbb = s.select('#outer').getBBox();
```

Then calculate the difference from the bounding box of the overall element vs the element being clicked on...

```
var bb = this.getBBox();
var diffX = outerbb.cx - bb.cx;
var diffY = outerbb.cy - bb.cy;
```

Then you can animate the transform including the difference as a translation.

```
this.animate({
                transform: 'T' + diffX + ',' + diffY + 'S3R360',
             }, 750, mina.easeout);
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fA2qYdGJ7oevj9VtURWN?p=preview)

Comment: Spectacular.  What path would you recommend taking in mastering Snap.svg?  Are there resources that have helped you that you would like to share?

Comment: Docs are at http://snapsvg.io/docs/ and getting started at http://snapsvg.io/start/, I also host a site of Snap examples that you can play with at http://svg.dabbles.info/  There is also a Google Group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/snapsvg